# Groovy/Grails :: Ruby/Rails :: 2011 State of the framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, frameworks

Yes, several similar threads exist, but we're now in 2011, and much has changed.

Grails 1.3.6 has improved hugely compared to v1.3 when I initially tried to learn the framework (and gave up to slow compile times and other groan inducing events).

Having spent a couple months with the latest release, I am impressed, protyping an app is an absolute breeze (GORM is great!). In development mode one no longer needs to restart, barring changes to domain classes. Groovy.lang is fantastic (bare in mind, this is compared to my day job life in PHP).

Now, on the flip side there is Ruby/Rails, which I have little experience with beyond perusing Ruby docs and exploring Active Record (to compare to GORM).  Coming from PHP/Jquery, groovy syntax is cake, ruby not so much, although accessible.

Ruby/Rails is all the rage, while Groovy/Grails seems to be picking up speed in its own right.

I'd like to hear what both camps have to say (flame inducing lang war welcome) re: pros/cons of both langs/frameworks now in 2011. When choosing a framework it's important to know what you're getting into, so have at it, newbies will benefit, and experts can vent ;--)

Comment: Please take a look at this great 2011 *real world benchmark* with web frameworks like Wicket, Tapestry, Lift, Rails and Grails and even JSP! http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Rails and Grails are both excellent frameworks with their current releases.  You really can't go wrong with either. Here are some things I find interesting about them though:

Rails

- Rails (Ruby) does not scale as well as Grails (Groovy). You will need more horsepower to run your application. This isn't a big deal at all with PaaS options like EngineYard (and hopefully a AWS BeanStalk Rails option in the future), but it might just cost a little more to run a Rails app vs a Grails app (obviously JRuby is also an option to though).
- Rails is slightly better with NoSQL alternatives currently, but Grails is catching up quickly
- Rails has many more plugins, but this can lead to trouble if you use some that aren't maintained (a lot of them don't currently work with Rails 3 yet either).
- Rails is more mature and has more features at this point in time because it's been around longer
- Rails REST support is amazing
- There are many more "big" Rails websites than Grails
- Ruby is much more popular than Groovy - [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)
- No dependence on Oracle, ha! (Grails obviously needs the JVM)

Grails

- Grails integrates with the JVM better than JRuby
- Grails GORM is better than ActiveRecord (IMHO), although Rails 3 opened the door a little bit for other persistence options, but all the books, tutorials, etc all use ActiveRecord
- Grails View taglibs are better than <=%...%> in view
- Grails plugins are well documented and clearly state whether they are supported by SpringSource or not
- SpringSource is investing heavily in Grails
- There will be many more corporate jobs for Grails than Rails in the future, but more startups use Rails (where do you want to work?)

My perspective

- I used Rails a couple years ago, I'm working on a Grails project now
- I like them both better than Django (Python) or Zend Framework (PHP)
- I plan to learn Lift (Scala) next

My Recommendation

- If you have never done Java development and are working on a side project for a small to medium website, go with Rails
- If you are working at a big company that uses Java, try pitching Grails to your management as the "next Java framework" they should invest in
- If you are working on "the next twitter or foursquare," well then you are smart enough to answer this question yourself! :)

Comment: Great, feedback @warner, looks like you have experience in both langs/frameworks. Not sure if I agree with, "If you have never done Java development...go with Rails" -- if you have done PHP, in some sense, at least syntactically, you already know Java, and by extension, Groovy. If you know javascript, you discovered closures and can quickly learn Groovy MOP. I want to learn Ruby/Rails, but the learning curve is much higher, just an entirely different coding paradigm. Note: camelCase is more "beautiful" than camel_case ;--)

Comment: The biggest issues about Rails for me it's the incompatibilities of gems between all the rails versions and all the ruby versions... It's insane compared to the jars that almost always works with any recent version (thanks to compilation)...

Answer (score 9):

First time I begun a project with Rails I was really surprised:

- How can I separate "repository" from "Service"?  Oh my God:  I have to put business logic on controllers... I can't imagine a real big project with Ruby on Rails:  Is there Someone on 37signals remembering the basics of separating Business and Domain/Repository.  The Rails folders/classes structure doesn't take care about this.
- Second sock: "Active Record". Try to design a real complex Object Oriented Business layer and map it using the Rails Models (Active Record)...  really: don't.
- 6 months later, with our project running:  R&R is consuming 80% CPU (and memory...) using  apache + passanger on a  quad core server... and the Postgresql Database is in holidays (3-4% of CPU)... Oh my god (newly)

  My old ASP/VB6 applications where capable of serve pages to 300 concurrent users in a real backoffice context with real complex databases and complex business installed on a standalone machine (a year 2001 1 CPU core server).

Of course, conventions and Ruby syntax are lovely... and no one needs a compiler (well...  unit tests are used for this porpouses 90% of the time... just for solving the dissapeared typing each time I change some code... "Please, programming god, take care about my fingers mistakes" )

First impession with Grails:

- A "Cool" stack inspired on Rails with professional power based on Spring framework (IoC, Hibernate, ...)

And YES!!!

- There is a clean Domain/Service separation. NICE!!!
- You can, eventually, forget Java.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken the Grails path as well. 2.0 is an enormous improvement. Still, I am unsure how things will pan out in production. I would have more confidence in a Scala solution (Play, Spray, Circumflex) at this point to be honest.  Grails has it all sure, but it also has it all (bugs/limitations).  No perfect solution, folks there is no perfect solution (if you have found it, however, please do let me know ;-))

Comment: Play with Scala is not perfect, too. All the nice convenience found in Play 1.2 with integration of JPA, an in memomory db, a db web front-end, a complete out of the box configuration is gone with Play 2. If you choose Scala, Hibernate/JPA is not a supported option anymore. You have to do ORM more or less by hand. And the Scala compiler is very slow. All in all I have to say that working with Grails is more fluent, even though I like Scala better than Groovy.

Comment: Whoever comes across this comment notice that the first two points are architectural anti-patterns only existing for historical reasons. Ayende explains why this design is crap: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tlMTJDKiug

Answer (score 5):

Rails is fairly mature, has a HUGE ecosystem to go with it. I'm not familiar with Grails or it's support online, but the red flag I see in your post is that you've admitted Grails is playing catch up to Rails.

Ruby is an absolute joy to work with (and this coming from an old C++ hack... why, back in the day I used to program with just a hex keypad, young whippersnapper... now GET OFF MY LAWN!).

There are things about ruby that make it hard to follow at times (method_missing I'm looking at YOU) but I'm sure that can be said about any language.

Me? I'd go with ruby and rails.

Comment: Nice, Rubyists tend to love the language I've noticed, preferring it to anything else (a good sign clearly). Re: Grails playing catch up, that may be true, I wonder though about performance in Ruby/Rails? JVM is powerful, and it seems Groovy++ will potentially be an alternative to Groovy.lang, which means near Java performance with a run-time app. -- that would blow any other existing framework out of the water performance-wise, no?

Comment: With jruby, you write and deploy a rails app on top of the JVM. The RedCar editor, written in ruby, runs on the  JVM and is impressively snappy.

Answer (score 3):

Well for grails, i still think that even catching up, it has 2 main things that rails won't have in a easy way:

- scaling up
- tons of mature java libraries at your fingertips (personally geotools among others)

Comment: Anyone who talks about "Java libraries" when comparing Grails/Rails is obviously coming from the Java camp. Java is a behemoth of a language and is losing traction from most new development houses. The reason why it's still this popular is because the "enterprises" are the ones using Java and paying universities to deliver Java programmers. The fact that they still teach "legacy ways" when teaching programming just proves that: they're manufacturing legacy developers/maintainers to replace the old, dying generation. And Grails is an attempt to adjust instead of REFORM. :)

Comment: @levi you would then be in the Ruby/Rails camp. Java does seem to suffer from code bloat; however, it does compile to bytecode and therefore blow away Ruby performance-wise. Sure, there's JRuby, but that runs on what, the JVM ;--) Scripting languages are the future; however, none of the existing scripting langs (with exception of perhaps budding Groovy++) can yet match compiled lang performance.

Comment: @levi yes i come from java world, but this is not true that java is artificially sustained by companies paying that. This is a very mature language used in many areas that other language have not surpassed. for instance GIS, because i know it well.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is outstanding - like the Pink Floyd of web dev.

Groovy on Grails is a decent copy of it - kind of like the Australian Pink Floyd show...

BTW - We have both at work - and I have seen many Grails developers eventually learn Rails and stick with it.

I have also seen Rails developers learn Grails, but NONE of them have preferred it.

About half of the time, our Java developers learn Grails and simply stay away from Ruby.

IMHO - If you truly know both fairly well,  you will almost always prefer Ruby and Rails.

Comment: a Rails devel would not prefer Grails, why would they? Time to start/restart server is what, 2 seconds?  Grails 2.0 it's minimum 20 seconds on quad core machine. The new reloading agent is great, but start/restart is painful when prototyping domains, making changes to abstract classes in src/groovy, or other must restart-to-see-changes action. Saying that, if you follow conventions and don't try to make Grails something it's not (or not yet, as in same-named controllers in separate packages, or @Mixin-able domains), it may be the "best" web devel framework on the JVM. Others may disagree ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes: you can use JRebel for instant application updates  http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/  it has groovy support

Comment: Grails is not a copy of Rails. It's an implementation of patterns which gained success and proved right for webdev like Convention Over Configuration, Active Record, and so on. Grails is domain-driven when Rails in database-driven, a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to consider your IDE. When I started out with rails, it was quite painful. Rubymine was super slow and crashing, everyone I know were using textmate. Grails has STS (eclipse based) and gives you all the features you need.

Comment: STS is completely awesome, all the more so given that I'm on Linux and IntelliJ looks like utter azz. Have noticed textmate appears to be the go-to editor for Rails developers: Mac-friendly hipsters ;-) I switched from OSX to Linux a couple of years ago and am not missing the spinning beach ball. In other news, now I'm wondering if learning Scala may be off the mark and that I should in fact at long last stop avoiding Rails. There is so much s*ck in the world of web frameworks, everywhere one limitation or another. Don't know, perhaps Rails is the, errr, holy Grail of web development after all

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a "best" solution. There definitely are a lot of great solutions out there. I wouldn't avoid Rails, truth is the transition to Rails would probably be easy given that you are already familiar with Grails.

Comment: It's petty, but my avoidance of Rails has been Ruby's syntax. For me, myCamelCase just feels more natural than my_camel_case. Obviously, one adjusts. I'm going to need to check out Rails since the Scala route is a bit premature for full stack web dev (bold statement, I know); limited reflection and no viable GORM/Active-Record alternative ORM solution exists yet. Would be ironic after 2 years of searching that I settle on Rails ;-)